# How do I inject a mock into my Rails unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, ruby-on-rails-5, static-methods, minitest

I'm trying to figure out how to inject a mock in my test, using Rails 5.1 and minitest.  I'm testing this method of the following class ...

```
module WebsocketClient
  class Proxy
    ...
    def connect
      @websocket = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect @websocket_url
```

I would like to have the line

```
WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect @websocket_url
```

return a mock instead of actually trying to connect, so I tried doing this in my unit test

```
  test "connect with open" do
    my_worker = my_workers(:one)
    assert my_worker.websocket_url.present?, "A pre-condition of this test is that the stratum worker have a websocket URL defined."
    proxy = WebsocketClient::Proxy.new( my_worker )

    # Stub call to connect
    mock_ws = MiniTest::Mock.new
    WebSocket::Client::Simple.stub(:connect, my_worker.websocket_url) do
      mock_ws
    end

    # Call the connect method
    ws_client = WebsocketClient::Proxy.new(my_worker)
    ws_client.connect
```

However, upon running my test, the mock is not getting executed.  Instead the "WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect @websocket_url" is being called as normal.  How do I inject my mock in my test?

Comment: Can you try moving `proxy = WebsocketClient::Proxy.new( my_worker )` lower after doing the mocking?

Comment: consider using mocha gem for stubbing and mocking. Minitest default mock provides limited functionality.

Comment: @TarumLalwani, I moved the "proxy = WebsocketClient::Proxy.new( my_worker )" line just before the comment starting with "# Call", but I get the same result (The "@websocket = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect @websocket_url" is not executing a mock but rather the real item).

Comment: I am totally new to `ruby`, but the `Call the connect method` block should be within `do .. end` of stubbing connect for mock in any language to work

Comment: @Gang, I'm having a hard time understanding what you are tryihng to describe.  Could you post a code example?

Comment: like this? `WebSocket::Client::Simple.stub(:connect, my_worker.websocket_url) do mock_ws ws_client = WebsocketClient::Proxy.new(my_worker) ws_client.connect end`